# How to have this definite integral?

Tags: integration

> Suppose that a function $f$ of $x$ and $y$ be defined as follows:$$f(x,y) =
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{21}{4}x^2y  & \text{for $x^2 \leq y\leq 1$,} \\
> 0 & \text{otherwise. }  \\
> \end{cases}$$
>   I have to determine the value of integral for which $y\leq x$ also holds.

The answer is $\frac{3}{20}$ and I also get it using figure for $x$ and $y$, but don't know how to get it with calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given condition $y\le x$and $x^2\le y\le1$ implies $x^2\le y\le x$.

Since $x^2\le x$, $0\le x\le 1$.

$$\int_{0}^1\int_{x^2}^x\frac{21}{4}x^2ydydx=\int_{0}^1\left[\frac{21}{8}x^2y^2\right]^x_{x^2}dx=\int_{0}^1\frac{21}{8}x^2(x^2-x^4)=\frac{21}{8}\left[\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^7}{7}\right]^1_{0}=\frac{3}{20}$$

Comment: Nice, but why $x^2<y<x$ and $x^2<y<x$ only?

Comment: Oh, many many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We find 
$$\int_{x=0}^1 \left(\int_{y=x^2}^{x}\frac{21}{4}x^2y\,dy\right)\,dx.$$
The integration with respect to $y$ gives $\frac{21}{8}x^2(x^2-x^4)$.
Integration with respect to $x$ yields $\frac{21}{8} \left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}\right)$. Simplify.

Comment: Sir, how did you choose values $x^2<y<x$ and $0<x<1$ ?

Comment: You had explicitly specified that the function was $x^2y$ for $0\le x^2\le y$, and $0$ elsewhere. You wanted the integral over the region where $y\le x$. That means we are integrating $x^2y$ with respect to $y$, $y=x^2$ to $y=x$. The part $x^2\le y \le x$ forces $x$ to travel from $0$ to $1$. A picture of the region of integration would help, one should automatically draw one in this kind of problem.   .

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}{{\rm e}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}$

> \begin{align}
> {\cal I}
> &
> \equiv
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}x\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}y\,
> {21 \over 4}\,x^{2}y\,
> \Theta\pars{y - x^{2}}\Theta\pars{1 - y}\Theta\pars{x - y}
> \\[3mm]&=
> {21 \over 4}\int_{-\infty}^{1}{\rm d}y\,y\quad
> \overbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}x\,
> x^{2}\,\Theta\pars{y - x^{2}}\Theta\pars{x - y}}^{\equiv\ {\cal J}}
> \end{align}

> \begin{align}
> {\cal J}
> &=
> -\,{1 \over 3}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}x\,
> x^{3}\,\bracks{%
> -2x\,\delta\pars{y - x^{2}}\Theta\pars{x - y}
> +
> \Theta\pars{y - x^{2}}\delta\pars{x - y}}
> \\[3mm]&=
> {2 \over 3}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}x\,x^{4}\,\Theta\pars{y}\,
> {\delta\pars{x - y^{1/2}} \over 2\verts{x}}\,\Theta\pars{y^{1/2} - y}
> -
> {1 \over 3}\,y^{3}\,\Theta\pars{y - y^{2}}
> \\[3mm]&=
> {1 \over 3}y^{3/2}\,\Theta\pars{y}\,\Theta\pars{y\bracks{1 -y}}
> -
> {1 \over 3}\,y^{3}\,\Theta\pars{y - y^{2}}
> =
> {1 \over 3}\pars{y^{3/2} - y^{3}}\Theta\pars{y}\Theta\pars{1 - y}
> \end{align}

> \begin{align}
> {\cal I}
> &=
> {7 \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{y^{5/2} - y^{4}}\,{\rm d}y
> =
> {7 \over 4}\pars{{2 \over 7} - {1 \over 5}}
> =
> \color{#ff0000}{\large{3 \over 20}}
> \end{align}